# Conditional observable transformation based on boolean observable in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

How can I edit my observable values based on boolean Observable, any time that this boolean observable will be changed then `$ships` observable will be transformed.

```
areShipsExpanded$: Observable<boolean>;
ships$: Observable<Ship>;

this.ships$ = this.shipsDataSource.getData().pipe(
    map(s => {
          if(this.areShipsExpanded$) {
              // do something with s
          } else {
              // do something else with s
          }
    return s;
})
```

and of course on view will be used `ships$ | async`

Above code is incorrect because Observable isn't transformed again when `this.areShipsExpanded$` would change.

Comment: What is incorrect about the code?

Comment: @user184994 I edited post.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `combineLatest` operator. This will give you an array of the latest emitted values so that you can perform your logic whenever any one of them changes. @RenéWinkler already posted an answer with code below, so I'll just leave [a link to the RxJS docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
areShipsExpanded$: Observable<boolean>;
ships$: Observable<Ship>;

this.ships$ = this.shipsDataSource.getData().pipe(
combineLatest(this.areShipsExpanded$),
map(([ships, expanded]) => {
      if(expanded) {
          // do something with ships
      } else {
          // do something else with ships
      }
return ships;
})
```

Comment: Based on the question I think OP is looking for combineLatest, not withLatestFrom

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Ohh I forogot that `combineLatest` can be used as operator as well... Thank you :)

Comment: @RenéWinkler I've noticed that I have to unsubscribe from `areShipsExpanded$` as well to avoid memory leak (in ngOnDestroy)? Why so?